# struggle when creating a block table with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink

I am trying to create a function that can create a block table that contains their Handle, FullName, BlockType, Parent by using struct. However, each time I get to enter a model name, it said

```
Error using struct
Field names must be non-empty character vectors or a string scalars.

Error in createBlockTable (line 10)
          tableStruct = struct(get(i), 'Name');
```

Here is my code

```
function blockTable = createBlockTable(modelName)
    load_system(modelName);

    getBlock = find_system(modelName, 'FindAll', 'on', 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'all', 'Type', 'Block');
    
    blockCell = cell(1,length(getBlock));

    for n = 1:length(getBlock)
       for i = getBlock(n, 1)
          tableStruct = struct(get(i), 'Name');
       end
    end
    
    blockTable = assign(tableStruct, blockCell); 
end
```

I am really confuse at i = getBLock(n,1). I think i just mess up with something in that line. BUt I do not know how to solve this problem. Please help, thanks

**UPDATE #1**
After a day I manage to solve it in a way but I do not know how to put all the struct in for loop to an empty cell

```
function blockTable = createBlockTable(modelName)
    load_system(modelName);

    getBlock = find_system(modelName, 'FindAll', 'on', 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'all', 'Type', 'Block');
  
    blockCell = cell(1, length(getBlock));
    
    for n = 1:length(getBlock)
        structTable = struct('Handle', get(getBlock(n), 'Handle'), 'Name', get(getBlock(n), 'Name') );
    end 
        
end
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on this line to see what `get(i)` is outputting? Per the error, I suspect it is an empty string, which can't be used as a struct field name.

Comment: I already know that get(i) cannot work, but I also use get_param but nothing change

Comment: use `get(i, 'Name')`, or `get_param(i, 'Name')`. The struct assignment is not going to work, since you also need to assign a value to a structfield. But you can collect the blocknames in a cell array.

Comment: I get it, but how to add all the name to the table in blockCell

Comment: also more, Error using struct
Conversion to struct from char is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a day, I have solved this question:

```
copyModel = 'sldemo_fuelsys_copy';

blockTable = makeTable(copyModel);

save('blockTable.mat','blockTable');

function blockTable = makeTable(modelName)

    load_system(modelName);

    getBlock = find_system(modelName, 'FindAll', 'on', 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'all', 'Type', 'Block');
  
    blockCell = cell(1, length(getBlock));
    
    for n = 1:length(getBlock)
    
        structTable = struct('Handle', get(getBlock(n), 'Handle'), 'Name', ... 
        get(getBlock(n), 'Name'), ...
        'Block_Type', get(getBlock(n), 'BlockType'), ...
        'Parent', get(getBlock(n), 'Parent') );
        
        blockCell{1, n} = structTable;
    
    end 
    
    blockTable = blockCell;

end
```

for my problem, mostly I am stuck at how to create struck for all the blocks in the model, so that I fix and using for loop to do it and also I assign my struct to cell that create early in this code.